# Regex, extract a href attribute from HTML with special name

Tags: java, regex

Having for example such a string:

`<a href="LINK_1" class="am"> Some Text</a>.. ANYTHING ..<a href="LINK_2" class="am"> Some Text</a><a href="SEARCHED_HREF_TO_EXTRACT" class="am"> SEARCHED_TEXT</a>..`

I need to extract from a HTML link a 'href' attribute value, from a link which contains some searched word like 'SEARCHED_TEXT' in example. Could you please advice, how to do it correctly? 
Would not ask if not sent much time already =)

I went till this, but unhopefully it works incorrectly..

```
String str = "<a href=\"LINK_1\" class=\"am\"> Some Text</a>.. ANYTHING ..<a href=\"LINK_2\" class=\"am\"> Some Text</a><a href=\"SEARCHED_HREF_TO_EXTRACT\" class=\"am\"> SEARCHED_TEXT</a>";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<a.*?href=\"(.*?)\".*SEARCHED_TEXT</a>");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0)); // matched whole string
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); // should be SEARCHED_HREF_TO_EXTRAC
```

I see that I need some negotation after href="(.*?)" to accept all symbols except

```
</a>
```

to find correct HREF, but can't make it work :(

Comment: you should use a HTML Parser not regex

Comment: Mandatory link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Try `"<a.*?href=\"([^\"]*)\"[^>]*>\\s+SEARCHED_TEXT</a>"`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use regex here as it is not proper tool to handle nested structures (at last regex flavor used in Java since it doesn't support recursion) like HTML/XML
(more info: [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg)).

Proper tool is HTML/XML parser. I would probably choose [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) because of its simplicity and CSS query support.

So your code could look like:

```
String html = "<a href=\"LINK_1\" class=\"am\"> Some Text</a>.. ANYTHING ..<a href=\"LINK_2\" class=\"am\"> Some Text</a><a href=\"SEARCHED_HREF_TO_EXTRACT\" class=\"am\"> SEARCHED_TEXT</a>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements links = doc.select("a:contains(SEARCHED_TEXT)"); //contains is case-insensitive
System.out.println(links.attr("href"));
```

or if you expect to find many links iterate over found Elements and get `href` attribute from each of them:

```
for(Element link : links){
    System.out.println(link.attr("href"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's much better :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, if I'm reading correctly, you want to extract href of links who's text matches a search term.

if this is the case, it can be achieved with slight modification of regex

```
    String str = "<a href=\"LINK_1\" class=\"am\"> Some Text</a>.. ANYTHING ..<a href=\"LINK_2\" class=\"am\"> Some Text</a><a href=\"SEARCHED_HREF_TO_EXTRACT\" class=\"am\"> SEARCHED_TEXT</a>";

    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("<a\\s*href=[\"']([^'\"]+?)[\"'][^>]*?>\\s*SEARCHED_TEXT\\s*</a>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(str);
    while (regexMatcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(regexMatcher.group(1));
    }
```

above code snippet, will extract only SEARCHED_HREF_TO_EXTRACT.