# How to extract text from an HTML page with java, using only loops and certain methods?

Tags: java, loops

I am trying to extract the text from an HTML page **without** using additional packages as it is actually a part of a cs course assignment. I am trying to write a method which omits any text between a '<' and a '>' and return anything that remains. I have a well-working method which extracts all page source and that method is on the parent class of the child class which I am currently working with.

```
public String getUnfilteredPageContents() {
    String last = "";
    String rawHTML = this.getPageContents();
    for(int i=0; i<rawHTML.length(); i++) {
      last = last + rawHTML.charAt(i);
      if(rawHTML.charAt(i) != '<') {
        while(rawHTML.charAt(i) != '>') {
          i++;
        }
      }
    }  
    return last;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should probably post the code you have already written.

Comment: If you have code that is "well-working", what are you asking?

Comment: Seems this is a frequent question recent days: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35532032/striphtmltags-exercise-in-java, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35530304/regex-extract-a-href-attribute-from-html-with-special-name. What about using the search function first? [java extract html](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=[java]%20extract%20html)

Comment: @SubOptimal It says "without using additional packages" in the question. All other links ask for a solution via RegEx or Scanner (if I read it correctly which I assume I did).

Comment: @Seth is absolutely right.

Comment: @SubOptimal what about reading the question first?

Comment: @ScottHunter the well-working method is the method which extracts the whole page source, I am trying to add something to that to make a new method extract only the text.

Comment: @orkalp When I post my first comment there was **no** code snippet from you in your question. And the requirement is close to the first link I posted. And on SO there are already so many questions to that context that I'm really sure there are pieces of code which you could use a basis.

Answer (score 2):

Here is very naive solution.

1. Load a webpage and put to very looooooong String.
2. Delete everything between `<>` brackets included.
3. Here is very simple Regex to spot a tag: `string.replaceAll("\(<.*?>\)", "");`

Comment: That's pretty darn neat, not gonna lie. Didn't think about that.

Comment: Neat indeed but I always apply naive solutions that are possibly wrong :D

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do fine. You need to write a loop for it if you want to have it run more than just once per input.

```
String s = "lalala <Hello from the other side> lalala"; //Your input
       s= s.substring(s.indexOf("<") + 1);
       s= s.substring(0, s.indexOf(">"));

System.out.println(s); //prints the letters inside the brackets
```

Always ensure that you are not exceeding the String-length (`.length`-method) while looping.